# SpringBoot doesn't change locale, but when I set -Duser.language=en, it works

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My web application has two locale en,de. In resources message bundle exists.

When I run application on my laptop, I can switch locate with parameter `lang`(lang=en or lang=de).

But when I moved jar to server, switching doesn't work.

But when I set `jar -Duser.language=en -jar some.jar`, lang works.

Can somebody write why it is works when `user.language` passed?

Comment: which OS is on your laptop, which is on the server?

Comment: both OS is Ubuntu 18.04. But in my laptop default locale is en_US.UTF-8, on the server locale is de_DE.UTF-8.